# How to count the array from specific JSON object value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

here is my javascript:

```
var json = '{"GetReportIdResult":[{"bulan":"4","total":"1728","type":"CHEESE1K","uang":"8796383"},{"bulan":"4","total":"572476","type":"ESL","uang":"5863408410"},{"bulan":"4","total":"33507","type":"WHP","uang":"235653242"},{"bulan":"5","total":"4761","type":"CHEESE1K","uang":"134877865"},{"bulan":"5","total":"245867","type":"UHT","uang":"1446787280"},{"bulan":"5","total":"47974","type":"WHP","uang":"631929807"},{"bulan":"6","total":"5762","type":"CHEESE1K","uang":"293393832"},{"bulan":"6","total":"236803","type":"UHT","uang":"2219506085"},{"bulan":"6","total":"24853","type":"WHP","uang":"386175022"}]}';
obj = JSON.parse(json);
var arrayobj = obj.GetReportIdResult.length;
alert (arrayobj);
```

I want to count how many `type` in the same `bulan` value, (e.g. there are 3 `type` = `CHEESE1K`, `UHT`, and `ESL`  in `bulan` = 4)

how to do that?

Comment: Your `json` variable doesn't actually hold JSON (which would be a string), it is assigned a reference to an object, so you don't need to use `JSON.parse(json)`.

Comment: @nnnnnn ops, my fault..haha I forget about that :p thank you to reminds me

Comment: There is a blank array element in this data!

Comment: @SomethVictory sorry, typo :p thanks to notice me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's still a typo in your JSON: you've got two commas in a row between the first two `"bulan":"6"` objects. But assuming you fix that...

If you're asking how to count distinct types for a particular `bulan` value you can do something like this:

```
function countTypesForBulan(resultArray, bulanVal) {
   var i,
       types,
       count = 0;
   for (i=0, types = {}; i < resultArray.length; i++)
      if (resultArray[i].bulan === bulanVal && !types[resultArray[i].type]) {
         types[resultArray[i].type] = true;
         count++;
      }
   return count;
}

console.log( countTypesForBulan(obj.GetReportIdResult, "4") );  // logs 3
```

The above loops through the array looking for a particular bulan value, and when it finds one it checks if it has already seen the associated type - if not, it adds it to the `types` object and increments the counter.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pAWrT/

Comment: I try it and it shows error log that says `Uncaught ReferenceError: type is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, try my updated version. I had accidentally put `type` where I meant `resultArray[i].type`. Fixed, as you can see in the demo.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, put the JSON into a string,
else your example code wont work.

var json = '{"GetReportIdResult":[{"bulan":"4","total":"1728","type":"CHEESE1K","uang":"8796383"},{"bulan":"4","total":"572476","type":"ESL","uang":"5863408410"},{"bulan":"4","total":"33507","type":"WHP","uang":"235653242"},{"bulan":"5","total":"4761","type":"CHEESE1K","uang":"134877865"},{"bulan":"5","total":"245867","type":"UHT","uang":"1446787280"},{"bulan":"5","total":"47974","type":"WHP","uang":"631929807"},{"bulan":"6","total":"5762","type":"CHEESE1K","uang":"293393832"},,{"bulan":"6","total":"236803","type":"UHT","uang":"2219506085"},{"bulan":"6","total":"24853","type":"WHP","uang":"386175022"}]}';

Then,
Iterate with `for` and count in a variable or a hashmap.

Since `GetReportIdResult` is an array, you can:

```
for( var i : obj.GetReportIdResult ){
    obj.GetReportIdResult[i] ... // Use at will.
```

Comment: Looks like you have some Java syntax in there :)

Comment: thank you for your answer :) but I still not understand how to use it to get what i want

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a `map` object which will contain the count for each `bulan` value. For example, `map['4'].count` will return 3.

```
var i, row, arr = obj.GetReportIdResult, map = {};
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    row = arr[i];
    map[row.bulan] = map[row.bulan] || {count: 0};
    if (map[row.bulan][row.type] === undefined) {
        map[row.bulan][row.type] = row.type;
        map[row.bulan]['count'] += 1;
    }
}
console.log (JSON.stringify(map));​
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amjibaly/mTuRU/).

Comment: well, the result is not like what I want, but this code is very useful for me, because after this I need to map the object :D thank you very much